# Hibernate delete orphan properly with join table - unidirection

Tags: hibernate

I have looked into several example on hibernate one-to-many unidirectional relation, but couldn't find how to remove orphan cascade from an existing list.

Assume that I have a class MyClass

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={
                    CascadeType.PERSIST, 
                    CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval=true)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
@JoinTable(name="enrolled_student", 
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="Class_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID") })
public List<Student> getStudentList() { return studentList;}
public void setStudentList(List<Student> studentList) { this.studentList = studentList;}
private List<Student> List;
```

If I have a list of students such as s1, s2, s3. And now I want to to remove student s2, I expected that the a row on s2 in table student will be removed as well as row in table enrolled_student on s2 id.

I have tried to do as:

```
Override
@Transactional
public void addStudentToClass(MyClass myClass, Student student) {
   MyClass attachedMyClass = classDao.merge(myClass);
   attachedMyClass.getStudentList().remove(student);
   classDao.update(attachedMyClass);
}
```

So I try to merge the `myclass` entity to prevent lazyinitializeviolation on loading the list of student. Then I remove the student from the list and update the list. But it keeps throwing a  `NullPointerException`.

I tried to work around this by deleting the row in student table with this:

```
public void deleteStudent(Student student) {
   studentDao.delete(student);
}
```

This is also doesn't work because the student is also existing in enrolled_student table.

Would you may show me a proper way to delete orphan please?

Comment: And the stack trace of the NPE is? What are all these merges and update calls? Start a transaction, get the MyClass instance, remove the student from the list, and commit the transaction.

Comment: I think I did what you are suggestion. To prevent laziIntializedExecption, I need to merge to get a persistent instance with the same identifier, then from it I remove student from the list and update the instance again. The stack trace couldn't help much.

Comment: It couldn't help **you**. But you're asking here for help, hoping to find experts knowing better than you. Hiding crucial information is not a good way to go. And I repeat: attached entities are... atached. Their state is made persistent automatically. Your call to classDao.update() is useless.